# Do not allow past date for drop in fullcalendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

Hi I am using fullcalendar for schdule event
Now I want to disable pas date for drop event, So I fixed using following solution

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  eventConstraint: {
    start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    end: '2100-01-01'
  },
});
```

It working fine, but now I want to disable few days from week too, so I added `dow` in `eventConstraint`, now its stop working

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  eventConstraint: {
    start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    end: '2100-01-01',
    dow: [ 3, 5 ]
  },
});
```

In short I want to disable past date and allow to select only `wed and fri` from calendar.

Is there anyway to fix issue.

Comment: AFAIK dow only works properly if there's no date part (i.e. times only in the associated start and end). You're trying to fulfil two requirements (1. past dates and 2. only weds and fri). Therefore my suggestion is to create 2 eventConstraints, one for each requirement. You can specify them as an array to the eventConstraint option. eventConstraint accepts exactly the same format of data that businessHours does - and there's a handy demo of an array-style set of options in the businessHours docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/businessHours/

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your help, I tried your solution but not working, even if create two eventConstraints, both scenario are stopped working.

  ```eventConstraint: [{
      start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      end: '2100-01-01', 
    }, {
       dow: [ 3, 5 ]
    }],```

Answer (score 0):

Having given this some more thought after your comments, I think this is best solved using some custom code, via the `eventDrop` callback:

```
eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
  var day = event.start.clone();
  day.startOf("day");
  var dayOfWeek = day.isoWeekday();
  if (day.isBefore(moment().startOf("day")) || (dayOfWeek != 3 && dayOfWeek != 5)) {
    revertFunc()
  }
}
```

This will check for both of your constraints: if the day is in the past, or that the day is not a Wednesday and not a Friday, then `revertFunc()` is executed, which is a fullCalendar-provided callback which sends the event back to its original location on the calendar.

Here you can find a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ughug9xx/2/

Comment: Thanks for your demo, I'll check and if it will work for me I will mark your answer as right. and thanks for your time again :).